# Fiddler4 with oracle virtual box

Tags: android, proxy, virtualbox, fiddler

Does anyone have any idea on how to use fiddler4 with Oracle VirtualBox. I am using this android OS.

http://www.andyroid.net/

I have tried to configure the proxy settings in the virtual box but it doesnt seem to be able to capture traffic.

Anyone has any idea on how about going to do this. I would prefer this emulator as it is faster than the android emulator in studio.

Comment: Me too! My configuration: WIndows 8.1 PC running VIrtualbox (Win 8.1 running Visual Studio 2015, Fiddler v4). Real Android device v4 (connected with USB cable - debugging from VirtualBox works fine). Real PC and Android are on the same wifi

Answer (score 0):

I did not have turned the Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox Network settings.

I found out this luckily by viewing the Mac article: http://www.telerik.com/blogs/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac

Configuring Fiddler for Android is here: http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler